# How to specify Dictionary<string,string> in ASP-all-route-data to pass query string

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have the following action link in my view `<a asp-controller="Messages" asp-action="Index">Connect</a>`

I need to pass a query string parameter with custom name (asp-route-id is in this case unacceptable) through `asp-all-route-data` is there a way how can I specify just the dictionary there, rather than creating new dictionary somewhere in the view and pass it to the attribute?

I have tried to do it following way, but without a luck.

```
 <a  asp-all-route-data="["user"=@item.PetSitter.UserId]" asp-controller="Messages" asp-action="Index">Connect</a>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify the Dictionary inline if you want, like this:

```
<a asp-all-route-data="@(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "user", item.PetSitter.UserId } })" asp-controller="Messages" asp-action="Index">Connect</a>
```

Comment: I haven't tested, but I think you can also do it as `<a asp-route-user="@item.PetSitter.UserId" asp-controller="Messages" asp-action="Index">Connect</a>`.  See [Anchor Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper#asp-route-value) for more info.